# OperationalError, no such column. Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am going through the Django REST framework tutorial found at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
I am almost finished with it and just added authentication. Now I am getting :

```
OperationalError at /snippets/
no such column: snippets_snippet.owner_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/snippets/
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: snippets_snippet.owner_id
Exception Location: /Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable:  /Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/tutorial',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/taylorallred/Desktop/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 11 Oct 2014 07:02:34 +0000
```

I have looked in several places on the web, not just StackOverflow for the solution, it seems like in general that the problem is with my database and need to delete it then remake it, I have done this several times, the tutorial even has me delete the database and remake it at the point.
Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter
from pygments import highlight


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())



class Snippet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
    highlighted = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                            default='python',
                                            max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                     default='friendly',
                                     max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Use the 'pygments' library to create a highlighted HTML
    representation of the code snippet.
    """
    lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)
    linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False
    options = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}
    formatter = HtmlFormatter(style=self.style, linenos=linenos,
                                      full=true, **options)
    self.highlighted = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)
    super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My `serializers.py`:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style', 'owner')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

My `views.py`:

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from snippets.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions

class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a nippet instance.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

And finally my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from snippets import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                                       namespace='rest_framework')),
)
```

DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "snippets_snippet" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"created" datetime NOT NULL, "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "code" text NOT NULL, 
"linenos" bool NOT NULL, "language" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "style" varchar(100) NOT NULL);
```

After doing some digging I found that when deleting and recreating the DB (as the tutorial says to) instead of using the `make migrations` command it would not only NOT add the columns but it would also not tell me something was wrong when running the `make migrations` command it tells me:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'highlighted' to snippet without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

If I comment out the `highlighted` section in `models.py` it will post the same message above but for the `owner` line. So it wants a default for both `highlighted` and `owner`, but I am not sure what to use as it. As well as the tutorial isn't helping me either on it.

Comment: If you deleted the db and reran syncdb I wouldn't expect you to have this problem. Are you sure you removed the correct SQLite db file?

Comment: I upvoted your question, not because of the question itself, but with the thoroughness of the details and upfrontness of what you have tried. Well presented questions are not so common. Unfortunatdly im on mobile and can't give an appropriate response. Good luck nonetheless.  Ill check back later to see how things are working out

Comment: I was not aware that I could be removing the wrong database. I run the command `rm tmp.db` and then `python manage.py syncdb` everytime I do so it prompts me to create a superuser which I do. I do this in the same terminal tab that I have done the rest of the project while also being in the same environment.

Comment: So any body else got a possible solution?

Comment: I had this too, I couldn't resolve it. Cloning the tutorial git and running sync seems to create the owner_id field in sqllite, but I couldn't get it to do it going through the tutorial.

Comment: Do the steps suggested by Gabriel Gunderson. And post the DB schema. That will help to debug further.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As you went through the tutorial you must have come across the section on migration, as this was one of the major changes in Django 1.7

Prior to Django 1.7, the syncdb command never made any change that had a chance to destroy data currently in the database. This meant that if you did syncdb for a model, then added a new row to the model (a new column, effectively), syncdb would not affect that change in the database.

So either you dropped that table by hand and then ran syncdb again (to recreate it from scratch, losing any data), or you manually entered the correct statements at the database to add only that column.

Then a project came along called `south` which implemented migrations. This meant that there was a way to migrate forward (and reverse, undo) any changes to the database and preserve the integrity of data.

In Django 1.7, the functionality of `south` was integrated directly into Django. When working with migrations, the process is a bit different.

1. Make changes to `models.py` (as normal).
2. Create a migration. This generates code to go from the current state to the next state of your model. This is done with the `makemigrations` command. This command is smart enough to detect what has changed and will create a script to effect that change to your database.
3. Next, you apply that migration with `migrate`. This command applies all migrations in order.

So your normal `syncdb` is now a two-step process, `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`.

Now, on to your specific problem:

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
    highlighted = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                            default='python',
                                            max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                     default='friendly',
                                     max_length=100)
```

In this model, you have two fields `highlighted` and `code` that is required (they cannot be null).

Had you added these fields from the start, there wouldn't be a problem because the table has no existing rows?

However, if the table has already been created and you add a field that cannot be null, you have to define a default value to provide for any existing rows - otherwise, the database will not accept your changes because they would violate the data integrity constraints.

This is what the command is prompting you about.  You can tell Django to apply a default during migration, or you can give it a "blank" default `highlighted = models.TextField(default='')` in the model itself.

Comment: What you say makes sense, however, shouldn't it also fix the problem if I delete the table? Since I would be recreating the table those fields would be there from the begninning right? But in practice (at least when I do it, I think I'm doing it right...) it still doesn't work, now however, when I run the `makemigrations` command it says all is well and "no changes detected", but when I go into the shell and look at the db schema it still doesn't show the `owner` or `highlighted` fields.

Comment: If you deleted the table,  you need to migrate again. There should be a folder called migrations in your app, see how many migrations there are.

Comment: The tutorial states to actually remove the sqlite file though, and run syncdb to recreate it. Even in this case the field was not created in the snippets_snippet table.

Comment: So currently my fields in my model look like `owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')` and `highlighted = models.TextField()` Should they look like `owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets', default='')` and `highlighted = models.TextField(default='')` ?

Comment: Ok, so far, it seems to be working, I completed the changes to the fields that I had in the previous comment posted. At the minium it is letting me continue on with the tutorial and giving me no errors, still not %100 sure if this completely fixed the issue but so far so good. If I run into any more issues down the road that coincide with this issue I will post an update here, otherwise if I have another issue that I can't solve I will post another question.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: I had the same issue and I fixed it by running `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: My confusion was, I had defined a field like `score = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)` which has kind of an inherent "default = NULL" value for new records, BUT I was still getting the error described by OP.  Explicitly setting "default=None" and then reapplying migrations fixed this issue.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I'm reviving this question because I have the exact same error and setup, but with a newer Django and Django Rest version.

Appears to be the same error:  `OperationalError: table snippets_snippet has no column named owner_id` 

The only difference is that , in views.py, `pre_save` has been replaced with `perform_create(self, serializer):`, for which the one line def is `serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)`. 

I tried setting `default=' '` in the TextField, but this did not solve the problem for Django 1.9. 
It fails when I try to add data, precisely on the .save() method

Answer (score 32):

Step 1: Delete the db.sqlite3 file.

Step 2 : $ python manage.py migrate

Step 3 : $ python manage.py makemigrations

Step 4:  Create the super user using $ python manage.py createsuperuser

new db.sqlite3 will generates automatically

Comment: you saved my life lol thanks

Comment: You saved me with step 1. This `db.sqlite3` was the reason of all my problems.

Comment: I have to specify `python manage.py makemigrations snippets`

Comment: This fixed my problem lol >>> Step 1: Delete the db.sqlite3 file.

Comment: Is this solution related to Sqlite3 only?
What if we are in production with PostgreSQL? In this case deleting the whole DB doesn't look a great idea.

Answer (score 13):

Let's focus on the error:

> Exception Value:
>   no such column: snippets_snippet.owner_id

Let's see if that's true...

You can use the manage.py command to [access your db shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell) (this will use the settings.py variables, so you're sure to connect to the right one).

```
manage.py dbshell
```

You can now show the details of your table by typing:

```
.schema TABLE_NAME
```

Or in your case:

```
.schema snippets_snippet
```

More sqlite commands can be found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) or by issuing a:

```
.help
```

Lastly, end your session by typing:

```
.quit
```

This doesn't get you out of the woods, but it helps you know what end of the problem to work on :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me how to access the sqlite shell (or whatever shell is config'd)...very awesome and don't know why I didn't learn about this sooner...Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I see we have the same problem here, I have the same error. I want to write this for the future user who will experience the same error.
After making changes to your class Snippet model like @Burhan Khalid said, you must migrate tables:

```
python manage.py makemigrations snippets
python manage.py migrate
```

And that should resolve the error.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 9):

Initially ,I have commented my new fields which is causing those errors, and run *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *python manage.py migrate* to actually delete those new fields.

```
class FootballScore(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='teams_football', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # match_played = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    # lose = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    win = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    # points = models.IntegerField(default='0')

class FootballScore(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='teams_football', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    match_played = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    lose = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    win = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    points = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

Then i freshly uncommented them and run *python manage.py makemigrations* and *python manage.py migrate* and boom. It worked for me. :)

Comment: Underrated answer.

Comment: worked for me ! thanks , maybe those dependencies causing the problem .

Answer (score 8):

This error can happen if you instantiate a class that relies on that table, for example in views.py.

Comment: *So Very Helpful* - Would give you many more +1's if I could. I'm practicing with object creation with Django models and had instantiated some class instances manually in `views.py`, rather than via a form submission, etc. Once I removed these creation events, I was able to `makemigrations` and `migrate` without the `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table {{project}}_{{app}} has no column named {{field_trying_to_add}}` error. Thank You!

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: @istiaque-ahmed This error happened to me when I was instantiating a class with a model on the level of the entire app. The migration mechanism was unable to check the attributes at the runtime and failed to execute changes for the particular model/table.

Answer (score 5):

The most direct way of solving this type of problem is just the following 3 steps process:

1. Delete all the migration related files from app's migrations folder/directory (these basically starts with `0001`, `0002`, `0003` etc).
2. Delete/Rename the existing database file named **db.sqlite3** from App directory.
3. Now run the following command:

   **`python manage.py migrate`**

   Finally execute

   **`python manage.py createsuperuser`**

   to perform the administrative tasks (If you want).

Comment: Really wished there was a faster way to do this. Then again, you can write a script to automate this process

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem and this is how I solved it.

1) Delete all the migration records from your app's migration directory. These are files named 0001_,0002_,0003_ etc. Be careful as to not delete the 
 _init__.py file.

2) Delete the db.sqlite3 file. It will be regenerated later.

Now, run the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate
```

Be sure to write the name of your app after makemigrations. You might have to create a superuser to access your database again. Do so by the following

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Thanks for stating that appname is also required while making migrations. This helped.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following

1. Delete my db.sqlite3 database
2. `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. `python manage.py migrate`

It renewed the database and fixed the issues without affecting my project. Please note you might need to do `python manage.py createsuperuser` because it will affect all your objects being created.

Answer (score 2):

You did every thing correct, I have been gone through same problem.
First delete you db and migrations
I solved my adding name of my app in `makemigrations`:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: suppose it is `mysql` db instead of the `sqlite3`?

Answer (score 2):

1.First delete only 0001_initial.py from migration file

2.Delete dbsqulite file

3.python manage.py makemigrations appname

4.python manage.py migrate

finally solved

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Burhan Khalid's answer and his comment about migrations: what worked for me was removing the content of the "migrations" folder along with the database, and then running manage.py migrate. Removing the database is not enough because of the saved information about table structure in the migrations folder.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Rishikesh. I too tried to solve this issue for a long time. This will be solved with either or both of 2 methods-

1.Try deleting the migrations in the app's migrations folder(except **init**.py)
  and then running makemigrations command

2.If that doesn't work, try renaming the model (this is the last resort and might get a little messy but will work for sure.If django asks "did you rename the model? just press N.").Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 1):

You did not migrated all changes you made in model. so
1) `python manage.py makemigrations`
2) `python manage.py migrate`
3) `python manag.py runserver`
it works 100%

Answer (score 1):

This may be one of the most annoying and time-consuming issue, the traceback is not helpful for solving the problem.

##### This means your database is messed up, which you must delete the database to start again.

It is worth-mentioning to restruct some existing field:

- When we tries to connect models, there are basically two ways:

> first one

```py
from comments.models import Comment

class Article(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)
```

> second one

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('comments.Comment')
```

The first method, widely used by beginners and it may cause **circular import issue**, which occurs when you tries to import `A.py` in `B.py` and in `B.py` it also imports `A.py`.

Therefore, we must abandon the first approach, and implement the second to all. Here's the way to solve the problem, unfortunately you need to delete the database.

- delete `db.sqlite3`
- for all apps, open `migration` folder, delete all except for `__init__.py`
- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

One the problem is solved, if you follow the convention, the issue will never occur again:

- **Do not import models** wherever you are, always use this instead:

```py
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)
# Article = apps.get_model('articles', 'Article')
```

in fields it can be briefed to string, which `<app_name>_<model_name>`

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('comments.Comment')
```

here is a script to delete all migrations, create a file `clean.py` at the same level to `manage.py`

```py
import os


def recursor(dirpath):
    # print(dirpath)
    delfiles = []
    deldirs = []
    with os.scandir(dirpath) as l1:
        for e1 in l1:
            if not e1.is_file():
                with os.scandir(e1.path) as l2:
                    for e2 in l2:
                        if e2.name == 'migrations':
                            with os.scandir(e2.path) as l3:
                                for e3 in l3:
                                    if not e3.name == '__init__.py':
                                        print(e3.path)
                                        if e3.is_file():
                                            delfiles.append(e3.path)
                                        else:
                                            deldirs.append(e3.path)
                                            with os.scandir(e3.path) as l4:
                                                for e4 in l4:
                                                    delfiles.append(e4)
    yn = input('are you sure to delete all the files above?(y/n)')
    if yn == 'y':
        for dp in delfiles:
            os.remove(dp)
        for dp in deldirs:
            os.rmdir(dp)



recursor(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is like mine, then this a workaround.
The good news is that you wont have to delete your db.

Check that there isn't some other model that uses this model as a reference.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: parts_part_type.blah
```

This was only happening to me because I had another model called "product" in a different app called "products" that referenced this model.

```
part = models.ForeignKey("parts.Part", related_name="some part", limit_choices_to={'part_type':Part_Type.objects.get(prefix='PART')},)
```

My solution was:

1. comment out the other app (in this case prodcuts) from **settings.py**
2. `python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate`
3. un-comment the other app so its enabled again.
4. `python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate`

Technically I think I need to change the `limit_choices_to` reference so

Comment: so this is a django bug, which has is not caused by incorrect user behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, even though on a different tutorial. I had the django version 2.2.3 so I thought I should not have this kind of issue.
In my case, once I add a new field to a model and try to access it in `admin`, it would say `no such column`.
I learnt the 'right' way after three days of searching for solution with nothing working.
First, if you are making a change to a model, you should make sure that the server is not running. This is what caused my own problem.
And this is not easy to rectify. I had to rename the field (while server was not running) and re-apply migrations.
Second, I found that `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` captured the change as opposed to just `python manage.py makemigrations`. I don't know why.
You could also follow that up with `python manage.py migrate <app_name>`. I'm glad I found this out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

just remember there is a **pycache** folder hidden inside the migrations folder so if you change your models and delete all your migration files you MUST delete the **pycache** folder also.

The only one you should not delete is your **init** file.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in `admin.py` I was querying from the table in which new `ForeignKey` field was added. So comment out `admin.py` then run makemigrations and migrate command as usual. Finally uncomment `admin.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If the error persists after doing what @Burhan Khalid said

Try this line: python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://wordpress.com/support/markdown-quick-reference/). Also, don't link your answer to someone other's, since it can be deleted, you can leave a [comment](stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you have enough [reputation](stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here:

Remove all migrations
Remove db.sqlite file

redo migrations

Answer (score 0):

I simple made a careless mistake of forgetting to actually apply the migration (migrate) after making migrations. Writing this just in case anyone might make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you skipped this steps...run the following commands to see if you had forgotten to execute them...it worked for me.

$ python manage.py makemigrations

$ python manage.py migrate

Thank you.

Comment: Someone already answered with this answer. What does your answer add?

Comment: It seems to be the same or only a subset of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60711785/12695027), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40770677/12695027), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669765/12695027), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56343380/12695027) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286896/12695027)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all your migrations in the migration folder of your django app, then run makemigrations followed by migrate commands. You should be able to get out of the woods.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with sqlite. My models.py looked all right. I did the following:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
.tables
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

Thru PRAGMA I was able to see that there was columns missing in the table failing.
I dropped all tables in the app. Be careful because this will make lose your data in the tables.

```
DROP table table_name
.quit
```

Then do this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app
python manage.py migrate your_app
python manage.py sqlmigrate your_app 0001
```

Then enter again to sqlite as follows and paste all the code you got from sqlimigrate:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
```

As an example, this is what I pasted inside sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE "adpet_ad" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "title" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "breed" varchar(30) NULL, "weight" decimal NULL, "age" integer NULL, "text" text NOT NULL, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "picture" BLOB NULL, "content_type" varchar(256) NULL, "name" varchar(100) NULL, "phone" varchar(31) NOT NULL, "gender_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "adpet_gender" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "owner_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "size_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "adpet_size" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "specie_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "adpet_specie" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "sterilized_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "adpet_sterilized" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "vaccinated_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "adpet_vaccinated" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting any existing migrations as some have said, do this:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake #(only if the below commands don't work)
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
python manage.py runserver makemigrations
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this because, if your problem persists, it might be that you are attempting to access the database in the **init** function of a class. The *makemigrations* process checks all of your modules and classes, and if you attempt to access a table in the database in the **init** function it might raise an error. Comment that line out and then try makemigrations and migrate

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a new fields you need to change in your database too so you need to run some commands to add a new column

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

If it's still not working delete your migrations files that name starts with 00 something similar and run those same commands from above. If it's still not working. delete SQLite database from your project and run those commands once again

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot speak particularly to the db aspect of the issue, or the answers...And I tried deleting the 0001_initial.py but the error persisted.

So for of you(us) experiencing the "*no such column: snippets_snippet.owner_id*" type of error with django (not necessarily REST), the issue is from the foreign key variable, it's expecting a default value which isn't specified.

Solution: add `default=''` to the foreign key arguments, and it you'll be fine. For context to this person's code; `owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets', default='')`

Answer (score 0):

##### Keeping SQLite database solution

Let's say for example I got this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: shop_product.likes

In order to keep your current SQLite database, you can do the following steps:

1. Connect to the SQLite database:

   ```bash
   sqlite3 db.sqlite3
   ```
2. Alter the the shop_product table, like this:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE shop_product ADD COLUMN likes;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I am also faced same problem.

If you're adding a new field then it gives the error as no column found.

Then you apply `make migration` command and after that `migrate` command
Then still same error..
EX...

```
 path=models.FilePathField()
```

Add default value for field

```
  path=models.FilePathField(default='')
```

and than apply command

```
  python manage.py makemigrations

  python manage.py migrate
```

It may help you