# OperationalError occurred while adding new fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a web app I've been managing for months, and I attempted to make some updates on my app. I added new fields to the existing class, but django raised an error.

These are what I've done.

**1. Added a new field to an existing model.**

```
class ExistingModel(models.Model):
    # Existing Fields
    new_field = models.IntegerField()
```

**2. Attempted to make migration**

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

However, it raised `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column` during this process.

- I added `django.contrib.sites` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.
- My django version is 2.0.3.

How can I add new fields to the existing model?

Comment: Look here. Can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312219/operationalerror-no-such-column-django