# OperationalError at /admin/app/review/ no such column: app_review.startup_id

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error whenever I open my Django admin page and click these models.

Here is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
import string
import random

code = get_random_string()

class Startup(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=code, unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   lead = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   problem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   solution = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Idea(models.Model):
   startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   summary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/idea')
   member = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   
   DRAFT = 'DRAFT'
   REVISED = 'REVISED'
   FINAL = 'FINAL'
   TYPE_CHOICES = [
      (DRAFT, 'Draft'),
      (REVISED, 'Revised'),
      (FINAL, 'Final'),
   ]

   type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)
   
   def __str__(self):
      return self.summary

class Comment(models.Model):
   startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   idea = models.ForeignKey(Idea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   member = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   GOOD = 'GOOD'
   FINE = 'FINE'
   BAD = 'BAD'
   RATING_CHOICES = [
      (GOOD, 'Good'),
      (FINE, 'Fine'),
      (BAD, 'Bad'),
   ]

   rating = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=GOOD)
   
   def __str__(self):
      return self.comment

class Product(models.Model):
   startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='attachment/product')
   version = models.IntegerField()
   changes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   member = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   
   INITIAL = 'INITIAL'
   IMPROVE = 'IMPROVE'
   FINISHED = 'FINISHED'
   STAGE_CHOICES = [
      (INITIAL, 'Initial'),
      (IMPROVE, 'Improve'),
      (FINISHED, 'Finished'),
   ]

   stage = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STAGE_CHOICES, default=INITIAL)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.changes

class Review(models.Model):
   startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   review = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   member = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   GOOD = 'GOOD'
   FINE = 'FINE'
   BAD = 'BAD'
   RATING_CHOICES = [
      (GOOD, 'Good'),
      (FINE, 'Fine'),
      (BAD, 'Bad'),
   ]

   rating = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=GOOD)
   
   def __str__(self):
      return self.review
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands? Any errors with those?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run migrations when you added these models?

```py
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

and did you add "app" to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make changes in your models, run:

```sh
$ python manage.py makemigrations

$ python manage.py migrate
```

to apply the changes in the DB.

[Migrations | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have made changes to the model and migrated again which would have caused problems in existing instances of the model or newly created model. So in your migrations.py folder delete the latest migrations and try remigrating

check this similar solution :

[operational errors: no such column solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26353756/8401179)