# OperationalError at /admin/ route of django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin, django-database

Hey I work with django framework I had the error `OperationalError`.

I have two classes with the same fields:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    First_Name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Last_Name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    ID_Number = models.CharField('Id Number', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Phone = PhoneNumberField('Phone',null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Lecturer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    First_Name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Last_Name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    ID_Number = models.CharField('Id Number', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Phone = PhoneNumberField('Phone',null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Lecturers"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

And I add a new field to my Student and also to Lecturer classes the field is

> ```py
> Phone = PhoneNumberField('Phone',null=True)
> ```

And yes I did the commands:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

After that I am sure that everything is updated:

```
Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: HomePage, accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
    No migrations to apply.
```

But when I run the *runserver* and after that, I go to the admin route:

> http://localhost:8000/admin

add I go the Lecturers data everything work great I have new field Phone:

[image: Lecturers]

But when I try to go to Student data I get an Error and don't recognize the field's phone!

[image: Student Error]

Comment: is column Phone created in your DB?

Comment: when i try to press on student option in administration i auto go the error so i dont no if its add, but for Lecturers it have the phone.. there has other way to check? if the field add to the data base? @TrueGopnik

Comment: Yes, but in you database like PostgreSQL, in your accounts_student table, do you have Phone column?

Comment: i dont used PostgreSQL, only the def database build in django db.sqlite3, so how can see? @TrueGopnik

Comment: Are you using PyCharm by any chance?

Comment: no, i using VScode @TrueGopnik

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite
You can install this and then check into your DB

Comment: ok i install and go to accounts_student and Phone is not there. what i should do? @TrueGopnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to lose `db.sqlite3` try to delete migrations first

Step 1: Delete the `db.sqlite3` file.

Step 2: `$ python manage.py migrate`

Step 3: `$ python manage.py makemigrations`

Step 4: Create a superuser using `$ python manage.py createsuperuser`

new `db.sqlite3` will generate automatically.

[Take a look at this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312219/operationalerror-no-such-column-django)