Operational Error in my Django Project as I can't find out why it is happening
I've been working on one of my projects while learning Django, and it's my first project based on follow-up tutorials. Now, I've almost completed my entire project, but there's one problem that keeps occurring, and I can't figure out why. There's a debug mode enabled, and it claims this is an operational error.
So, this problem occurs as I am developing an online commerce shop and have created a conversation app that allows users to talk with the Admin about the items. However, when the user enters the text message and presses the submit button, an error message such as "operational error" appears. Even I can't see the message from the Django admin because it also displays the debug error message there.
Clicking up on Contact seller
Following that, this trace error notification showed up, which I don't know what it meant.
OperationalError at /inbox/4/
no such column: conversation_conversationmessage.content
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/4/
Django Version: 5.0.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: conversation_conversationmessage.content
Exception Location: D:\Python Django project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 329, in execute
Raised during:  conversation.views.detail
Python Executable:  D:\Python Django project\env\scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.9
Python Path:    
['D:\\Python Django project\\puddle',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0',
 'D:\\Python Django project\\env',
 'D:\\Python Django project\\env\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Aug 2024 15:08:20 +0000


Seems like you are missing a column in your table. Your conversation_conversationmessage table is missing content column. Checkout this similar question. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312219/operationalerror-no-such-column-django
